# Generic function that sums Vec<T> for types implementing use std::iter::Sum;

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to create something with Command pattern and came up with something like this:

```
trait Command {
    fn execute(&self);
}

struct PrintSum {
    params: Vec<i32>
}

impl Command for PrintSum {
    fn execute(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.params.iter().sum::<i32>());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let command = PrintSum { params: vec![1, 2, 3, 4] };
    command.execute()
}
```

which works perfectly, but then (mostly for practicing xd) I wanted to make `params` in `PrintSum` a `Vec<T>` where `T` is generic. I knew I'm going to have to add `where` keyword and tell that T implements Debug + Sum<&'a T> so after few iterations of solving issues with compiling I came up with this:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::iter::Sum;

trait Command {
    fn execute(&self);
}

struct PrintSum<T> {
    params: Vec<T>,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Command for PrintSum<T>
where
    T: Sum<&'a T> + Debug,
{
    fn execute(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.params.iter().sum::<T>());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let command = PrintSum {
        params: vec![1, 2, 3],
    };
    command.execute()
}
```

however this still doesn't compile with this info:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:17:38
   |
17 |         println!("{:?}", self.params.iter().sum::<T>());
   |                                      ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined here...
  --> src/main.rs:16:16
   |
16 |     fn execute(&self) {
   |                ^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:17:26
   |
17 |         println!("{:?}", self.params.iter().sum::<T>());
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
  --> src/main.rs:12:6
   |
12 | impl<'a, T: 'a> Command for PrintSum<T>
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/main.rs:17:45
   |
17 |         println!("{:?}", self.params.iter().sum::<T>());
   |                                             ^^^
   = note: expected `Sum<&T>`
              found `Sum<&'a T>`
```

[Playground](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b?code=%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0A%0A*%2F%0A%0Ause%20std%3A%3Afmt%3A%3ADebug%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aiter%3A%3ASum%3B%0A%0Atrait%20Command%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20execute(%26self)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20PrintSum%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20params%3A%20Vec%3CT%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3C%27a%2C%20T%3A%20%27a%3E%20Command%20for%20PrintSum%3CT%3E%0Awhere%0A%20%20%20%20T%3A%20Sum%3C%26%27a%20T%3E%20%2B%20Debug%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20execute(%26self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20self.params.iter().sum%3A%3A%3CT%3E())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20command%20%3D%20PrintSum%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20params%3A%20vec!%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20command.execute()%0A%7D)

I tried to solve this by changing `Vec` into `&'a Vec` and claiming that it has the same lifetime as elements used in `Sum` and it somehow worked:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::iter::Sum;

trait Command {
    fn execute(&self);
}

struct PrintSum<'a, T> {
    params: &'a Vec<T>,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Command for PrintSum<'a, T>
where
    T: Sum<&'a T> + Debug,
{
    fn execute(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.params.iter().sum::<T>());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let command = PrintSum {
        params: &vec![1, 2, 3],
    };
    command.execute()
}
```

So I have to questions:

- how did it solve the problem, I thought that solution would have something to do with the note:  `expected Sum<&T> found Sum<&'a T>`,
- how to solve it without changing params from Vec to &Vec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `impl Command for PrintSum` is *too* restrictive about lifetimes.  What you need is for `T` to implement `Sum<&'a T>` for *any* lifetime `'a`, not a specific one that is bound to `T`.  You can express this with a [higher-rank trait bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) (also called HRTB):

```
impl<T> Command for PrintSum<T>
where
    T: for<'a> Sum<&'a T> + Debug,
{
    fn execute(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.params.iter().sum::<T>());
    }
}
```

Comment: First time seeing `for` in where clause and it's exactly what I needed. Also I pretty much felt that I'm doing somewhat spaghetti with lifetimes here, now I understand what I did wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @Miokloń No problem! This stuff can be very confusing at first -- and, honestly, sometimes it still takes me a bit to work out exactly what lifetime bounds should be.

Answer (score 2):

If you know you're going to stick with `Copy` types (such as `i32`), you can use that to avoid references altogether

```rust
impl<T: Copy> Command for PrintSum<T>
where
    T: Sum<T> + Debug,
{
    fn execute(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.params.iter().copied().sum::<T>());
    }
}
```

Otherwise the HRTB solution is best.